# Why is Xcode 6.1 using paths from an old folder?

Tags: swift, build, xcode6.1

I downloaded an Apple Objective-C sample app on my Macbook, and it was placed into the Downloads folder.  I unzipped and moved the folder into Documents and am trying to do a mix-and-match conversion to Swift.  I've migrated one of the classes to Swift and am trying to build, but it's failing with this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: bridging header '/Users/alan/Downloads/examples/MyTest_ios/Classes/MyTest_ios-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist
```

because the compile command is using paths pointing to Downloads, specifically for the bridging header file:

```
-import-objc-header /Users/alan/Downloads/examples/MyTest_ios/Classes/MyTest_ios-Bridging-Header.h
```

The project's Build Settings for the *Swift Compiler - Code Generation* setting for *Objective-C Bridging Header* is set to:

```
Classes/MyTest_ios-Bridging-Header.h
```

The properties for the bridging header file are:

```
Type: Default - C Header
Location: Relative to Group
Full Path: /Users/alan/Documents/MyTest_ios/Classes/MyTest_ios-Bridging-Header.h
```

I've scoured the Build Settings paths and everything looks fine, what am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I modified the *Objective-C Bridging Header* value to be the full path instead of relative to the Classes sub-folder, and now the compile gets past that error.  I still would like to know why Xcode was using the old folder's path... a bug in 6.1?

Comment: I had the same problem, I think manually deleting the build folder did the trick for me, I also wrote the relative location in the project settings (it was only in the target settings) either one of those refresh the path value, I searched in the project file package contents for the old path, found nothing